# Adjustable spray jet tips keep getting clogged

Tags: drip-system

I installed a drip system for my garden using mostly 180 degree and 90 degree adjustable spray jets on spikes (got them from Home Depot).

[image]

I keep running into a problem where the tips get clogged. I'm guessing there's some insect crawling into them for the dampness. I've unscrewed the tip and turned the water on to make sure nothing in the line was clogged it and everything appeared fine - I've even replaced the tip with a new one and it worked fine again... until it gets clogged again of course.

Does anyone know of a way to clean the tips out?

Comment: Do you have one of those drip connection kits that includes a filter or is there a filter somewhere in the system?

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY I don't believe there is a filter in the system... at least, I can't recall having ever installed one.

Comment: Best used with 150 mesh screen filter. It's amazing what kind of sediment is in the water. Then you only have to worry about mineralization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most drip components I'm aware of, including this micro sprinkler you're using are very susceptible to clogging. It is not uncommon for there to be sediment in the water supply that will clog the filters which is why manufacturers of these systems also provide filter kits that will screen out sediment.

What you have is a DIG micro sprinkler. If you want to stick with the same manufacturer you can get the DIG D57A Hose Thread Screen Filter if your system is hose connected. If it's connected to your irrigation system there are special control valves for drip systems that I believe include a filter or one can be added inline. If it's connected to a converted sprinkler Rainbird has a conversion kit that includes a a filter.

One more ting to note about these systems is they usually work best with low pressure in the 10-15 psi range. This one is rated for up to 30psi but I believe is meant to be used at 25 psi.

Usually a connection to a drip system involves 3 components. A hose-bib vacuum breaker to prevent water from flowing backwards into your home in the event there's an unusual pressure drop in the main line, a pressure regulator and a screen filter. All three of these should be available at your local Home Depot where you purchased the sprinklers. Each of them currently costs less than $10 with the filter being the most expensive.

Comment: I looked up some info on the pieces I installed and the timer I set up has a built-in filter... so, my guess is that the filter isn't the issue, unless there's something I'm missing here.

Comment: @jhawes what's the brand and model number of the timer?

Comment: Here is a link: http://www.homedepot.com/p/DIG-Solar-Powered-Irrigation-Timer-with-Anti-Siphon-Valve-ECO1ASV-075/203766359

Comment: @jhawes I looked through the manual of the item you linked to and nowhere in the manual do the words filter exist nor is a filter depicted in any of the diagrams. Since you're using that type of valve your irrigation is plumbed into your water supply and not using a spigot connected system. In that case I think you may need something like this combo filter/pressure regulator http://www.homedepot.com/p/Orbit-2-in-1-Pressure-Regulating-Drip-Filter-67798F/202541802

Comment: Also if you look at the reviews, one of the review pictures shows a picture of an installation that has a filter installed in the system but it's not part of the timer/valve.

Comment: @jhawes and since you're using an anti siphon valve you don't need to add a vacuum breaker. Just make sure the valve is installed high enough above the tallest part of your irrigation system so it functions properly.

Comment: thanks for catching that! I'll definitely go install that filter then - sounds like that's the issue.

Comment: @jhawes you're welcome. There are other options besides that one I linked to. Thought it was neat that it had pressure regulator and filter in one. If you can't get a hold of that one there should be separate regulator and filters. Since you're using an anti siphon valve I'm assuming it's plumbed with PVC pipe. To make it easy to connect look for regulator or filter that says "pipe thread" or NPT and not hose thread or GHT. That way you can just use regular PVC fittngs to put it in your system.

Comment: You're correct about that - all PVC. I'm actually installing it right now... well in a couple of minutes.